# MySQL query not executing, what is the issue?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I can't figure out what this MySQL query isn't working.

```
$add = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `members` (`id` ,`grade` ,`last` ,`first` ,`email` ,`schedule` ,`phone` ,`committees` ,`dues`)
        VALUES (NULL , '$grade', '$last', '$first', '$email', '$schedule, '$phone', '$committees', '$dues'
    )");
```

I get this error:

> Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near, 'FBLA Week\nPartnership w/Business', '1' )' at line 2

I can't see what the problem is with the code. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Your Script is prone to SQL-Injections. Make sure you sanitize your input!

Comment: @TimWolla We don't know that for certain, but it's always a good reminder to double-check.

Comment: @Wiseguy You are right, but anyway you should sanitize it as late as early to not disrupt any other parts that don't like the backslashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a closing quote after `$schedule`.

```
'$schedule,
```

Answer (score 2):

You have not closed the `'` fter `$schedule`